# Create a a segment with the given number of verts and hook and empty to every verts in the segment

Tags: python, blender, segment, vertices

How can I create a segment with for example 30 verices and then connect an empty with an Hook parenting to every veritces in the segment, all this via Python in Blender 3d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say that this was frustrating but after trying several different approaches this is the one way that I got to work.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

num_verts = 30

scn = bpy.context.scene
D = bpy.data.objects

verts = []
edges = []
for i in range(num_verts):
    verts += [(i, 0.0, 0.0)]
    if i > 0:
        edges += [(i, i-1)]

mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("hooked verts")
mesh_data.from_pydata(verts, edges, [])
mesh_data.update()
obj = D.new("Hooked line", mesh_data)
obj.select = True
scn.objects.link(obj)
scn.objects.active = obj

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

for i in range(len(obj.data.vertices)):
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.verts[i].select = True
    bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()
    bpy.context.selected_objects[0].name = 'Hook'
    bm.free()

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

To assign a hook to a vertex, the object needs to be in edit mode with the desired vertex selected. It would seem that the add hook operators make a mess of the edit mesh data so that after the first hook modifier is created the mesh data is no longer valid. The solution - re-create the bmesh data and select a vertex after creating each hook.